# Order of Operation for python

Tags: python

My question is to solve

`result = 8 - 4 ** 3 / 5 // 2 % 15 * 2`

This is what I did

First: 4^3=64

second: 5//2=2

third: 64/2=32

4th: 32%15=2

5th: 2*2=4

final: 8-4=4

I expected the output of 8-4=4 but the actual output was -4.0.

Comment: You may have learned "order of operations" back in elementary school math, but even in math, it's really about argument grouping, not about what order you perform operations in. In math, you can perform operations in any order that respects the argument grouping; in Python, it's generally left-to-right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result = 8 - 4 ** 3 / 5 // 2 % 15 * 2`

In your particular case, the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is as follows:

First, `**`

Second, `*`, `/`, `%`

Third `-`

If more than one operator has the same precedence they are applied from left to right in the order they appear. Applying the previous that was stated, you have the following:

```
8 - 64 / 5 // 2 % 15 * 2
8 - 12.8 // 2 % 15 * 2
8 - 6.0 % 15 * 2
8 - 6.0 * 2
8 - 12.0
-4.0
```

Comment: Answer seems truncated